# For line in : not returning all lines

Tags: python, dictionary, readlines

I am trying to traverse a text file and take each line and put it into a dictionary. Ex:
If the txt file is
a
b
c

I am trying to create a dictionary like

word_dict = {'a':1, 'b:2', 'c':3}

When I use this code:

```
def word_dict():
fin = open('words2.txt','r')
dict_words = dict()
i = 1
for line in fin:
    txt = fin.readline().strip()
    dict_words.update({txt: i})
    i += 1
print(dict_words)
```

My dictionary only contains a partial list.  If I use this code (not trying to build the dictionary, just testing):

```
def word_dict():
fin = open('words2.txt','r')
i = 1
while fin.readline():
    txt = fin.readline().strip()
    print(i,'.',txt)
    i += 1
```

Same thing.  It prints a list of values that is incomplete.  The list matches the dictionary values though.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're trying to read the lines twice.

Just do this:

```
def word_dict(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as input_file:
        words = {line.strip(): i for i, line in enumerate(input_file, 1)}
    return words

print(word_dict('words2.txt'))
```

This fixes a couple things.

1. Functions should not have hard coded variables, rather you should use an argument. This way you can reuse the function.
2. Functions should (generally) `return` values instead of printing them. This allows you to use the results of the function in further computation.
3. You were using a manual index variable instead of using the builtin `enumerate`.

This line `{line.strip(): i for i, line in enumerate(input_file, 1)}` is what's known as a dictionary comprehension. It is equivalent to the follow code:

```
words = {}
for i, line in enumerate(input_file, 1):
    words[line.strip()] = i
```

Comment: @Noob123 Glad I could help!

Comment: Could you help explain the 'I for i' portion of the code.  From what I have read, enumerate() in this example will start at 1 and give each line a value?  how exactly is the dictionary getting updated?

Comment: Sure, that line is what's known as a [dictionary comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). It's similar to a list comprehension, but it uses slightly different syntax to create a dictionary instead of a list.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  Found some good stuff on Dictionary Comprehensions.  [link](http://www.diveintopython3.net/comprehensions.html)

Comment: @Noob123 I'm glad! If you wouldn't mind accepting this answer (click the little check mark under the voting arrows), that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are calling the `readline()` function twice. Simply do:

```
def word_dict():
    fin = open('words2.txt','r')
    dict_words = dict()
    i = 1
    for line in fin:
        txt = line.strip()
        dict_words.update({txt: i})
        i += 1
    print(dict_words)
```

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks.  So if I understand, when I write 'For line in fin:' it counts as calling readline(), then when I call readline () as a part of txt = fin.readline() that is the second time?